# Convert pandas DataFrame to nested JSON array

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as follows:

```
                dates  values
0 2020-01-01 00:15:00    25.7
1 2020-01-01 00:30:00    25.0
2 2020-01-01 00:45:00    24.6
3 2020-01-01 01:00:00    24.6
4 2020-01-01 01:15:00    25.0
5 2020-01-01 01:30:00    25.6
6 2020-01-01 01:45:00    26.2
7 2020-01-01 02:00:00    26.5
8 2020-01-01 02:15:00    26.3
9 2020-01-01 02:30:00    25.7
```

and I do:

```
df = df.to_json(orient='records', date_unit='s')
print({'items' : df})
```

It gives me output as follows:

```
{
    "items": "[{\"dates\":1577837700,\"values\":25.7},{\"dates\":1577838600,\"values\":25.0},{\"dates\":1577839500,\"values\":24.6},{\"dates\":1577840400,\"values\":24.6},{\"dates\":1577841300,\"values\":25.0},{\"dates\":1577842200,\"values\":25.6},{\"dates\":1577843100,\"values\":26.2},{\"dates\":1577844000,\"values\":26.5},{\"dates\":1577844900,\"values\":26.3},{\"dates\":1577845800,\"values\":25.7}]" }
```

I want the output to look like

```
{
    "items": [[1577837700, 25.7],[1577838600,25.0],[1577839500,24.6],[1577840400,24.6],[1577841300,25.0],[1577842200,25.6],[1577843100,26.2],[1577844000,26.5],[1577844900,26.3],[1577845800,25.7]] }
```

That is, from the output that I get from my code, I want to have all the records in the form of a `list` instead of a `dict`

Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `orient="values"`:

```
df.to_json(orient='values', date_unit='s')
```

```
'[[1577837700,25.7],[1577838600,25.0],[1577839500,24.6],[1577840400,24.6],[1577841300,25.0],[1577842200,25.6],[1577843100,26.2],[1577844000,26.5],[1577844900,26.3],[1577845800,25.7]]'}
```

This just dumps out the `.values` (or `.to_numpy`) output as json. See [`DataFrame.to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) for more.